# Schema mapping issue

Tags: dxa

I am getting this error:

> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No semantic mapping found between Schema 810 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:Item) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.EntityModel'

I am working without the Core and I have created my Page, Entity and Region Views.  I have a simple Schema/Model (Item) but I am getting the error when I run the application.  I think the issue is in my Schema but I am not sure what I need to do to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message implies that your View Model has a (semantic) property of type `EntityModel`, which is an abstract base class.

It is fine to have such a property (mapped to a Component Link field), but since it is not possible to instantiate an abstract class, the model mapping has to find a suitable concrete sublass. It uses the semantic mapping on Schema/type level for that purpose.

Concretely, you must have a **registered** View Model type which maps to the Schema of the linked Component.

The error message shows that the semantic type name of the Schema is `Item` in the DXA Core Vocabulary (probably the root element name of your Schema is `Item`). Now you need a **registered** View Model type which is called `Item` or is annotated with `[SemanticEntity(EntityName="Item"]`.

Comment: Thanks RIck, exactly right.  I registered the View Model incorrectly and when I updated to: RegisterViewModel("Item", typeof(Item)); it worked.

Comment: Do you really have a View called "Item" for that View Model? Often, this is not the case for such *embedded* View Models. In that case, you can also use `RegisterViewModel(typeof(Item));`